# Can I have a custom protocol on java type URL?

Tags: java, url, kotlin

I'm writing (in Kotlin) below, and all good

```
val url = URL("http://my-page/content?page=0")
```

However, I'm trying to make a customer scheme (i.e use "myprotocol" instead of "http").

```
val url = URL("myprotocol://my-page/content?page=0")
```

It will crash `Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: myprotocol`

Is there a way for me to have it allow a custom protocol?
i.e. I want to use it same as normal URL format, so I could extract the path, query etc, except that the protocol (scheme) is a custom one.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for [Custom Protocol](http://mjremijan.blogspot.com/2012/02/create-your-own-java-url-handlers.html)

Comment: Use URI, not URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JBNizet answer is perfect. Just use

```
val url = URI("http://my-page/content?page=0")
```